# Move Magento from remote to local server

Tags: magento, wamp

I'm running:

WAMP on Windows 8
Apache Version: 2.4.2
PHP Version: 5.4.3
MySQL Version: 5.5.24
I've all the module needed for Magento active. I try to install a fresh copy of Magento and it works without problems (except the login issue that i fixed).

I did the following steps:

copy all files from remote server by ftp to www/mysite (mysite is a sub folder of the WAMP's www folder)

dump the remote db (adding drop table istruction) and imported in the local db (checked the data in local.xml)

replaced all the ocurrency in the db (http://www.mysite.it) with

```
    (http://localhost/mysite)
```

the tables secure_url and unsecure_url both have the final /

Now I would just run "magento-cleanup.php" to set permission but I receive the following error:

Not Found

The requested URL /mysite/ was not found on this server.

The same thing for every page (home, admin).

Can anyone help?ell.

Comment: Please fix your title.

Comment: Is the error on your local machine? It seems like you have put your files in the wrong folder - try adding a simple "index.html" to your document root, to see if that works, and then ensure your "crespigioielliit" folder is in the right relative location, and contains an index file.

Comment: Hi ,what's wrong whit the title??btw neither a simple html file works in that folder...how's ythat possible...the others directories works good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Not Found

The requested URL /mysite/ was not found on this server.

 FYI - you are getting this error because you using wrong address
```

Here is the clean way of migrating magento from Remote server to localhost.

As you have mentioned that you have copied all the file from remote server to www/mysite.

SO while accessing the localhost site you should use this link localhost/mysite

and before accessing instead of changing the secure and unsecure url manually, you should let the mogento do all the necessary changes by itself.

for that first take backup and delete the following file app/etc/local.xml and than access localhost/crespigioielli, after that magento installation will be triggered. Good Luck